# Google App Engine - Datastore - Get an entity, not by it's key

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm building an Android app, and I'm using Google App Engine to store user's data. I want users to be able to connect from other devices to their account, but I could not figure how.

The users table (kind) has 4 properties: `id, email, nickname and level`:[image]

I have read this:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/creating-entities

It's written their that I can only get entities by their key, and it's a problem for me, because in a new device, I can only get the user's email, not the key and Id. **I need to get the key and id by their email.**

**Is this possible?**
**If it's not, is their any other solution?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do a simple `query`.  What language are you using in the GAE backend?  For example, in Python, you would do something like:

```
def get_user_by_prop(prop, value):
    this_user = User.query(getattr(User, prop) == value).get()
    return this_user
```

Judging from the link in your question, I assume you are using Java?  Here are the docs for a query:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/retrieving-query-results

where they use the example:

```
Query q =
    new Query("User")
        .setFilter(new FilterPredicate("nickname", FilterOperator.EQUAL, "billybob"));

PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
Entity result = pq.asSingleEntity();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

What is stored at the `id` property? Does it have some meaningful value or just random unique number to be used as a unique identifier?
It seems like you can design your database differently so the email address would be your unique identifier. In that case, you will have a `User` table contains the following properties:
`email` *(your unique identifier)*, `nickname` and `level`.
That way you will be able to use the following code snippet:

```
Key userEmail; //Get user's email
Entity user = datastore.get(userEmail);
```

---

Regardless of that, you are still able to access your entity without the need for the entity's key, by using a `query`. That way you won't be using the entity's key in order to get its instance but you would rather get the desired entity by using the given property value and finding the matching entity with that property value.
The query would look something like that:

```
String userEmail; //Get user's email
Filter propertyFilter =
    new FilterPredicate("email", FilterOperator.EQUAL, userEmail);
Query q = new Query("User").setFilter(propertyFilter);
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
try {
    Entity user = pq.asSingleEntity()
    //Same as Entity user = datastore.get(userEmail) mentioned above

} catch (TooManyResultsException e) {
    // If more than one result is returned from the Query.
    // Add code for dealing the exception here
}
```